# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Screen Lock not working randomly

Tags: suspend, 20.04, power-management, lock-screen, lid

I recently updated to 20.04 LTS and I've been having some trouble with lock screen. When I close the lid it is configured to suspend and lock and the suspend part is ok but when I open the lid, most of the time it is unlocked by itself without asking for password. And also sometimes it works and asks for password just completely random.
I changed logind.conf but didn't help:

```
[Login]
#NAutoVTs=6
#ReserveVT=6
#KillUserProcesses=no
#KillOnlyUsers=
#KillExcludeUsers=root
#InhibitDelayMaxSec=5
#HandlePowerKey=poweroff
#HandleSuspendKey=suspend
#HandleHibernateKey=hibernate
#HandleLidSwitch=suspend
#HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=suspend
HandleLidSwitchDocked=suspend
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
#HoldoffTimeoutSec=30s
#IdleAction=ignore
#IdleActionSec=30min
#RuntimeDirectorySize=10%
#RemoveIPC=yes
#InhibitorsMax=8192
#SessionsMax=8192
```

And I'm using GNOME.

Comment: check in StartupApplications if there is something called ignore-lid-switch-tweak and report back

Comment: @kannzzmm2 No there's only im-launch, NVIDIA X Server Settings, SSH Key Agent and a couple more non related programs. Also suspend when laptop lid is closed is turned on in tweaks.

Answer (score 1):

So I disabled "Extensions" in Tweaks and it got fixed. I turned Extensions on and seems like everything's fine and the lock screen is fixed. It was probably a bug with an extension and it got removed as I switched it off and on.

Answer (score 0):

Cyb3r4dd1ct's advice worked out for me. However I decided to figure out what exact extension was causing the problem, and [Gtile](https://github.com/gTile/gTile) was the culprit.

Edited:
It's apparently a known issue [gnome-shell 3.36 crashing on screen lock/unlock](https://github.com/gTile/gTile/issues/124).
You need to upgrade gnome-shell to at least 3.36.3-1:

```
$ gnome-shell --version
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade gnome-shell
```